# mysql comparison and encoding

Tags: mysql, encoding

I have a problem with MySQL here, it's quite strange actually... it's a real headbreak, I've been trying a lot of things, sticking some COLLATE, CAST, CONVERT,... but nothing, maybe i'm not doing it the right way, but I'm really lost here.

If some pro has a tip ;) here is my problem:

```
SELECT col FROM tabl LIMIT 0,1
```

returns: helloworld01

```
CASE WHEN((SELECT col FROM tabl LIMIT 0,1) = 'helloworld_01') THEN 'ok' ELSE 'ko' END
```

returns: ok

```
CASE WHEN(SUBSTR('helloworld_01',1,1) = 'h') THEN 'ok' ELSE 'ko' END
```

returns: ok

BUT and this is where it get strange

```
 CASE WHEN(SUBSTR((SELECT col FROM tabl LIMIT 0,1),1,1) = 'h') 
 THEN 'ok' ELSE 'ko' END
```

returns: ko

after manually checking each letter i found that the result is quite strange ... numbers and letters in correct order but each character isn't the one supposed to be ... i get something like lsuejwodhb_65
 .... but do not change at each request ... and they do not matche their CHAR code either ....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because in your below query it's not always guaranteed to output `helloworld_01` unless you have only one row which is very rare; since you have not used any `order by` clause. So the data returned may be different and so your condition is not matching at all. To be sure use a order by clause. Again, without an `order by` using `LIMIT` clause makes no sense.

```
SELECT col FROM tabl order by col LIMIT 0,1
```

Try your strange query like below and see if it matches this time

```
CASE WHEN(SUBSTR((SELECT col FROM tabl order by col LIMIT 0,1),1,1) = 'h') 
 THEN 'ok' ELSE 'ko' END
```

Comment: hey, thanks for the answer, but the table is 1 row long .... i should have said that :)

Comment: @user1906731, then it's absolutely not possible. See a proof here http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/49bd5/2 for my claim. consider accepting the answer if it helped.

Comment: hey, thanks for the link I didn't know SQLFidle ... kewl :) though I still have my problem, and I can asure you that what I describe is what is happening, same is with SUBSTR(user(),... or any global var... But I am using python, talking to php, talking to SQL so maybe there is part of the reason here ....  ?!!!

Comment: @user1906731, then that's not the issue at DB end rather your application end. Probably the specific mysql driver you are using. You can always open a separate question thread with all that information.

Comment: *grumpy* !!! I'm in a kinda stuck situation here ... but well ... thanks Rahul ;) so you think I can't figure this out by set character set someswhere ? (I don't have enough reputation to mark ur answer...)

Comment: @user1906731, you don't need reputation to mark the answer. Being a question owner you can mark it as answer just by clicking the check button under voting button.